# prometheus is not able to talk to influxDB

Tags: kubernetes, influxdb, prometheus

I am running prometheus as a kubernetes pod and wants prometheus to write data to the inflluxDB I have added the entries to the prometheus.yml , below entries been added

remote_read:
    - url: "http://localhost:8086/api/v1/prom/write?u=xxxxxx&p=ids3pr0m&db=xxxxxx"
  remote_write:
    - url: "http://localhost:8086/api/v1/prom/read?u=xxxxxx&p=ids3pr0m&db=xxxxxx"

the pod is running file and able to read it , but keep on giving me below error .

```
time="2018-05-03T17:38:31Z" level=warning msg="Error sending 100 samples to remote storage: server returned HTTP status 400 Bad Request: {"error":"proto: wrong wireType = 2 for field StartTimestampMs"}" source="queue_manager.go:500"
time="2018-05-03T17:38:31Z" level=warning msg="Error sending 100 samples to remote storage: server returned HTTP status 400 Bad Request: {"error":"proto: wrong wireType = 2 for field StartTimestampMs"}" source="queue_manager.go:500"
time="2018-05-03T17:38:31Z" level=warning msg="Error sending 100 samples to remote storage: server returned HTTP status 400 Bad Request: {"error":"proto: wrong wireType = 2 for field StartTimestampMs"}" source="queue_manager.go:500"
```

Can someone help me on this

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this as well and for me it was using a Prometheus version 2.x. 
[Looks](https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb/issues/10247#issuecomment-418369632) InfluxDB only supports version 1.8